# Set http headers for multiple handlers in go

Tags: go

I'm trying to set an http header for multiple handlers. My first thought was to make a custom write function that would set the header before writing the response like the code sample at the bottom.

However, when I pass a pointer to the http.ResponseWriter and try to access it from my function it tells me that "type *http.ResponseWriter has no Header method".

What is the best way to set headers for multiple handlers, and also why isn't the pointer working the way I want it to?

```
func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    type Message struct {
        Name string
        Body string
        Time int64
    }

    m := Message{"Alice", "Hello", 1294706395881547000}

    b, _ := json.Marshal(m)
    WriteJSON(&w, b)
}

func WriteJSON(wr *http.ResponseWriter, rawJSON []byte) {
    *wr.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    io.WriteString(*wr, string(rawJSON))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/json", HelloServer)

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil)
    if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("ListenAndServer: ", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about the multiple handlers thing, but I do know why the code you wrote is failing. The key is that the line:

```
*wr.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

is being interpreted, because of operator precedence, as:

```
*(wr.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json"))
```

Since `wr` has the type `*http.ResponseWriter`, which is a pointer *to* and interface, rather than the interface itself, this won't work. I assume that you knew that, which is why you did `*wr`. I assume what you meant to imply to the compiler is:

```
(*wr).Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

If I'm not mistaken, that should compile and behave properly.

Comment: Actually, you don't need that dereference. Go automatically inserts dereferences whenever neccessary. Downvoted because misleading. Will remove downvote upon fix.

Comment: Interesting that go should automatically dereference the pointer because it doesn't seem to in this case. wr.Header didn't work *wr.Header didn't work either. The only thing that works is when I wrap it in parens. (*wr).Header works fine.

Comment: Hahah ok, I'll roll back the change. I'll also look that up at some point. I think the confusion might have been that go uses the "." operator to mean both local and pointer function calls (so pass by value and pass by reference), which isn't quite the same thing as this.

Comment: I wish I had time to delve into this deeper. This should definitely be documented somewhere because it's a bit of a gotcha that could prove extremely frustrating.

Comment: @SethArcher and joshlf, perhaps you figured this out already, but the ultimate reason is that because the argument is a pointer to an interface, this is actually a pointer to a pointer to an unexported type hidden in the interface.  It should be `func WriteJSON(wr http.ResponseWriter, ...` instead of `func WriteJSON(wr *http.ResponseWriter, ...)`.  Rarely should a pointer to an interface be used.  Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39927655/2778484).

Comment: Header().Add() method can be used to set the 'Content-Type' header twice but it depends on the client how it would be interpreted. In my case, I had 'Content-Type' set to 'application/json' in a wrapper and when I used Header().Add(), it simply added another 'Content-Type' in the response. The first one was only being seen by Chrome on iOS whereas every other client I tested with was okay with the most recently set header.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `*wr` as it already references a pointer.

`wr.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")` should be sufficient.

If you want to set "global" headers for every request, you can create a function that satisfies `http.HandleFunc` ([go.auth has a good example](https://github.com/bradrydzewski/go.auth/blob/master/auth.go#L199)) and then wrap your handlers like so:

`http.HandleFunc("/hello", Defaults(helloHandler))`

Also take a look at the `net/http` documentation, [which has further examples](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServeTLS).

Answer (score 0):

I wrap my handlers with an error handler 
which calls my AddSafeHeader function.

I based it on http://golang.org/doc/articles/error_handling.html
but it doesn't use ServeHTTP so it works with appstats:

```
http.Handle("/", appstats.NewHandler(util.ErrorHandler(rootHandler)))
```

Here:

```
package httputil

import (
  "appengine"
  "net/http"
  "html/template"
)

func AddSafeHeaders(w http.ResponseWriter) {
  w.Header().Set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
  w.Header().Set("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block")
  w.Header().Set("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN")
  w.Header().Set("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains")
}

// Redirect to a fixed URL
type redirectHandler struct {
  url  string
  code int
}

func (rh *redirectHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  Redirect(w, r, rh.url, rh.code)
}

func Redirect(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, urlStr string, code int) {
  AddSafeHeaders(w)
  http.Redirect(w, r, urlStr, code)
}

// RedirectHandler returns a request handler that redirects
// each request it receives to the given url using the given
// status code.
func RedirectHandler(url string, code int) http.Handler {
  return &redirectHandler{url, code}
}

func ErrorHandler(fn func(appengine.Context, http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) func(appengine.Context, http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
  return func(c appengine.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    defer func() {
      if err, ok := recover().(error); ok {
        c.Errorf("%v", err)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        errorTemplate.Execute(w, err)
      }
    }()
    AddSafeHeaders(w)
    fn(c, w, r)
  }
}

// Check aborts the current execution if err is non-nil.
func Check(err error) {
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}

var errorTemplate = template.Must(template.New("error").Parse(errorTemplateHTML))

const errorTemplateHTML = `
<html>
<head>
        <title>XXX</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h2>An error occurred:</h2>
        <p>{{.}}</p>
</body>
</html>
`
```

Answer (score 0):

[`http.ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) is an interface.

You should probably not be using a pointer to an interface.  In net/http/server.go, the unexported `response` struct is the actual type that implements `ResponseWriter` when the server calls your handler, and importantly, [when the server actually calls the handler's ServeHTTP](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L1579), it passes a **`*response`**.  It's *already* a pointer, but you don't see that because `ResonseWriter` is an interface. (the response pointer is created [here](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L1532), by [(c *conn).readRequest](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L744).  (The links will likely be for the wrong lines the future, but you should be able to locate them).

That's why the `ServeHTTP` function required to implement `Handler` is:

```
ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request)
```

i.e. not a pointer to `ResponseWriter`, as this declaration already permits a pointer to a struct that implements the `ResponseWriter` interface.

Answer (score 0):

As I am new to Go, I created a minimal contrived example, based on elithrar's answer, which shows how to easily add headers to all your routes / responses.  We do so, by creating a function that satisfies the `http.HandlerFunc` interface, then wraps the route handler functions:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"


    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)


// Hello world.
func Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode("Hello World")
}

// HelloTwo world
func HelloTwo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode("Hello Two World")
}

// JSONHeaders conforms to the http.HandlerFunc interface, and
// adds the Content-Type: application/json header to each response.
func JSONHeaders(handler http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        handler(w, r)
    }
}

func main() {   
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    // Now, instead of calling your handler function directly, pass it into the wrapper function.
    router.HandleFunc("/", JSONHeaders(Hello)).Methods("GET") 
    router.HandleFunc("/hellotwo", JSONHeaders(HelloTwo)).Methods("GET")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router))
}
```

#### Results:

```sh
$ go run test.go &
$ curl -i localhost:3000/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 28 Feb 2019 22:27:04 GMT
Content-Length: 14

"Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

What i end up doing:

```golang
// Accepts a user supplied http.HandlerFunc and then modifies it in various ways. In this case, it adds two new headers.
func CommonlHandler(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func (rs http.ResponseWriter, rq *http.Request) {
        rs.Header().Add("Server", "Some server")
        rs.Header().Add("Cache-Control", "no-store")
        h(rs, rq)
}

// somewhere down the line, where you're setting up http request handlers

serveMux := http.NewServeMux()

serveMux.HandleFunc("/", CommonHandler(func(rs http.ResponseWriter, rq *http.Request) {
    // Handle request as usual. Since it's wrapped in the CommonHandler and we've set some headers there, responses to requests to "/" will contain those headers.
    // Be mindful what modifications you're doing here. If, for ex., you decide you want to apply different caching strategy than the Common one, since this will be passed to the CommonHandler, your changes will be overwritten and lost. So it may be a good idea to introduce checks in CommonHandler to determine whether the header exists, before you decide to create it.
}))

serveMux.HandleFunc("/contact", CommonHandler(func(rs http.ResponseWriter, rq *http.Request) {
    // handle another request as usual
}))
```